# Network Service account does not accept local paths

Tags: path, windows-services, user-accounts, network-drive, network-service

I am creating a program that runs as a service and creates database backups (using pg_dump.exe) at certain points during the day. This program needs to be able to write the backup files to local drives AND mapped network drives.

At first, I was unable to write to network drives, but solved the problem by having the service log on as an administrator account. However, my boss wants the program to run without users having to key in a username and password for the account.

I tried to get around this by using the Network Service account (which does not need a password and always has the same name). Now my program will write to network drives, but not local drives! I tried using the regular `C:\<directory name>\` path syntax as well as `\\<computer name>\C$\<directory name>\` syntax and also `\\<ip address>\C$\<directory name>\`, none of which work.

Is there any way to get the Network Service account to access local drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this problem by creating a new user at install time which I add to the Administrators group. This allows the service to write to local and network drives, without ever needing password/username info during the setup.

Answer (score 1):

Just give the account permission to access those files/directories, it should work. For accessing local files, you need to tweak ACLs on the files and directories. For accessing via network share, you have to make changes to file ACLs, as well as permissions on network share.

File ACLs can be modified in Exploler UI, or from command line, using standard `icacls.exe`. E.g. this command line will give directory and all files underneath Read, Write and Delete permissions for Network Service.

```
icacls c:\MyDirectory /T /grant "NT AUTHORITY\Network Service":(R,W,D)
```

File share permissions are easier to modify from UI, using `fsmgmt.msc` tool.

You will need to figure out what *minimal* set of permissions necessary to be applied. If you don't worry about security at all, you can give full permissions, but it is almost always an overkill, and opens you up more if for any reason the service is compromised.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This solution looks like it would work, but I've already gone another way. Instead of using the Network Service user, I create my own user and add it to the Administrators user group, so I don't need to ask the user for any password/username info.